# Use of chance (チャンス)

Tags: usage

Was wondering if it is natural to use 「チャンス」in Japanese sentences.

For example, 「本を読むチャンスになって」

It feels somewhat natural, as I likely heard it in a manga, but wanted to see if it was okay to use it in normal speaking/text messaging.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to express with this?

Comment: チャンス is a common word, but its meaning is not the same as *chance* in English. Your example sentence ("Turn into an book-reading opportunity"?) makes no sense.

Comment: @naruto So would きっかけ be more appropriate in this sort of usage/nuance?

Comment: @naruto To clarify what my comment meant:  would 本を読むきっかけになって make better sense.  To say in English, "it became an opportunity to read a/my book" does make sense.

Comment: @A.Ellett 本を読むきっかけになって is a valid sentence, but I'm not sure if that was what OP wanted to say.

Comment: It's all up to the context if 本を読むチャンスになって make sense. If the speaker got a short spare time to read a book, it would be a チャンス.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

### Meaning

While it's a phonetically transcribed word from "chance", its meaning also covers "opportunity".

チャンス implies a chance of doing what you wanted to do sometime. It MAY be somewhat sudden and/or unexpected.

[機会]{きかい} is a synonym of チャンス. The difference is a bit similar to "opportunity" and "chance".

### Example 1, written sentence

```
[明日]{あす}の[予定]{よてい}がキャンセルになった。[家]{いえ}で[積]{つ}んでいた[本]{ほん}を[読]{よ}むチャンスだ。

(Tomorrow's plan has been canceled. It's a chance to read my unread books.)
```

### Example 2, spoken sentence

```
[前]{まえ}の[走者]{そうしゃ}が[疲]{つか}れてきた[今]{いま}がチャンスだ！[追]{お}い[抜]{ぬ}くぞ！

(The runner in front of me is getting tired, now it's my chance! Gonna overtake him!)
```